# Export R environment to YAML (including package list) in order to recreate the environment somewhere else

Tags: r, containers, yaml, conda

I am trying to export my R environment (including the list of active packages) as a YAML file in order to recreate the same R environment in a container (or a different machine). I know there are other ways and formats, but I need a YAML file to encapsulate the environment.

Anaconda makes it easy in Python:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Can't seem to find a way to do it in R. The closest representation that I found is `sessionInfo()`.

Can anyone help me with this task?

Comment: When you say "including the list of active packages" what else are you including from your environment, all variables as well? What will you do with  this yaml file on the other machine, install specific versions of packages? R environments are very different from python environments.

Comment: No, I am interested in the environment build, not in variables, data, or objects. By environment build I mean: R version, attached base packages, and other attached packages with corresponding versions. I would take this YAML file and basically recreate the exact same build on a different machine.

Comment: From Anaconda "conda env export" command, the YAML looks like this:\s\s name: py27
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- alabaster=0.7.9=py27_0
- pygments=2.1.3=py27_0
- pylint=1.6.4=py27_1
- pyqt=5.6.0=py27_1
- python=2.7.13=0
- python.app=1.2=py27_4
- pip:
  - jupyter==1.0.0
  - jupyter-client==4.4.0
  - numpy==1.12.0
  - packaging==16.8
  - pandas==0.19.2
  - prompt-toolkit==1.0.10
  - py4j==0.10.4
  - pyparsing==2.1.10
  - python-dateutil==2.6.0
  - python-utils==2.0.1
  - scikit-learn==0.18.1
  - scipy==0.18.1
prefix: /Users/

Comment: @Henry did you end up figuring this out? Running into similar issues now.

Comment: the only way is to use R inside Anaconda. In that case, you can simply use the command outlined above. Exporting directly from R right now is not an option and, even if it were possible, would take considerable amount of custom work

Comment: any update now?  conda-develop or something?